# how to pass dictionary value to arithmetic functions in different classes of python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, oop, python-class

> I am trying to pass a dictionary value to a simple arithmetic
>   functions. I am using 3 classes.ClassA have add() sub() mul() div() functions defined.Class B contain only values used for operations. Class c having some checks.ClassA look like these.

```
class ClassA(object):

    def addition(self, x, y):
        return x + y

    def substraction(self, x, y):
        return x - y

    def division(self, x,y):
        return x / y

    def multiplication(self, x, y):
        return x * y
```

> ClassB looks like this.

class ClassB(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.var1 = 2
    self.var2 = 8
```

> and here is ClassC

```
from File1 import ClassA
from File2 import ClassB

class ClassC(ClassB):

    def __init__(self,ClassB):
        self.var3= ClassB.var1
        self.var4= ClassB.var2
        print(self.var3)#testing
        print(self.var4)#testing

    def checkWholeNumber(self):
        if self.var3%2 ==0 or (self.var3+1)%2 & self.var4%2 == 0 or (self.var4+1)%2:
            print(self.var3) #if value is whole then it will print some value or will throw exception

            return True
        return False
    def addDictAndAss(self):
        myDict={}
        myDict["x"]=self.var3
        myDict["y"]=self.var4
        print(myDict) #to check whether values are added or not
object1 = ClassB()
object2 = ClassC(object1)
object2.checkWholeNumber()
object2.addDictAndAss()
object3= ClassA()
object3.addition(*myDict)
```

> > Now I want to assign my created dictionary to functions of the classA. Thanks in advance.
> >     Edit1:File1.py contain ClassA ,File2.py contain ClassB, File3.py contain ClassC

Comment: There are some problems in your `__init__` method in `ClassC`. But separately, what is `addDictAndAss` supposed to do? Add a dictionary to the instance? Or return it to the caller? Or both? Currently it does neither, it just computes `myDict` but then discards it.

Comment: Actually I am new to python. `__init__` method may have a problem some problem, moving towards `addDictAndAss` what my aim is method should add values to a dictionary and that dictionary I want to pass to those functions in classA.

Comment: why do you use variables in `__init__` that are exactly the same as class names`? this is confusing.

Comment: why do you use binary & instead of `and` ?

Comment: ugh, typos, please ignore that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#Step1:

```
 class ClassA(object):

    def addition(x, y):
        X=x
        Y=y
        return X + Y
def substraction(x, y):
    X = x
    Y = y
    return X - Y

def division(x, y):
    X = x
    Y = y
    return X / Y

def multiplication(x, y):
    X = x
    Y = y
    return X * Y



   #step2:
class ClassB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 10
        self.var2 = 8



 #Step3:
    from File1 import ClassA
    from File2 import ClassB
    
    class ClassC(ClassB):
    
        def __init__(self,ClassB):
            self.var3= ClassB.var1
            self.var4= ClassB.var2
            #print(self.var3)#testing
            #print(self.var4)#testing
    
        def checkWholeNumber(self):
            if self.var3%2 ==0 or (self.var3+1)%2 & self.var4%2 == 0 or (self.var4+1)%2:
               # print(self.var3) #if value is whole then it will print some value or will throw exception
                return True
            return False
        def addDictAndAss(self):
            myDict={}
            myDict["x"]=self.var3
            myDict["y"]=self.var4
            #print(myDict) #to check whether values are added or not
            print("Please select one arithmatic operator i.e. '+','-','/','*'")
            operator=input()
            if operator == '+':
                add=ClassA.addition(**myDict)
                print(add)
            elif operator == '-':
                sub=ClassA.substraction(**myDict)
                print(sub)
            elif operator == '/':
                div=ClassA.division(**myDict)
                print(div)
            elif operator == '*':
                mul=ClassA.multiplication(**myDict)
                print(mul)
    
    # Creating object and calling(assiging)
    object1 = ClassB()
    object2 = ClassC(object1)
    object2.checkWholeNumber()
    object2.addDictAndAss()
    object3= ClassA()
```

Please suggest a better way to do this.